# how join four collections in MONGODB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need your Help..
I have 4 collections ..
Country:

```
{Country:[
     {
        "MENU": "CNTY",
        "DESP": "India",
        "CODE": "IND"
    }]
}
```

State:

```
{
    State: [
        {
            "MENU": "STATE",
            "CNTY": "IND",
            "DESP": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "CODE": "AP",
            "TINCODE": "37"
        }]
}
```

District

```
{District:[
         {
    "CODE": "504",
    "DESP": "KADAPA",
    "STATE": "AP",
    "CNTY": "IND"
}
]}
```

Town

```
{Town:[{
            "Menu": "TOWN",
            "CODE": "AP03546",
            "District": "504",
            "DESP": "Abbavaram",
            "Pincode": "516270"
        }]
}
```

i have tried with aggregate and lookup

```
DBclient.db("Dictionary").collection("Country").aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: "State",
      localField: "CNTY",
      foreignField: "CODE",
      as: "states"
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: "$states"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Districts",
      localField: "states.CODE",
      foreignField: "STATE",
      as: "district"
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: "$district"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Towns",
      localField: "district.CODE",
      foreignField: "District",
      as: "towns"
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: "$towns"
  }
]).toArray();
```

I got `null` array. What's wrong with this query ..plz give me suggestions.

Comment: There is no `CNTY` field in `Country` collection.

Comment: Yes , Thanks, Updated , Its working